# Where to install a Build Machine for Windows product, on windows server or target product (for example: windows 7)

Tags: build, jenkins, build-automation

I am setting up a Jenkins build server for Windows product targeted for Windows 7 (some day also Windows 8). It should compile C++ & C# code.
I would like to ask regarding best practice where to deploy the build server, On target platform (Windows 7) or on Windows Server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It will be best to deploy on the Windows Platform as it would be a good practice to isolate your Jenkins build server from your targeted machine. If something goes wrong with the target machine your Jenkins setup will be available which can help you in saving time and repeating the work again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a setup, where you install the Jenkins Master (the web interface) on any machine that is suitable (personally i would prefer a linux server, but that's just my opinion, in your case i'd suggest the Windows server), and then on your target platform setup a Jenkins slave, where the actual build is executed. So you have your build machine separated from the Jenkins master, which is then just responsible for launching the builds and providing the web interface with all the build statistics. If the target machine breaks, Jenkins is still accessible and you can workaround that break e.g. by just setting up another slave.